# How to parse xml in varnish

Tags: xml, parsing, curl, response, varnish

I intend to use vmod_curl to submit a request from Varnish. The server returns 200 & xml response in the body. I'd like to parse this xml response. Can you please tell me if there is any way to do it? (vmod,...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're into VMOD territory. Varnish will not parse XML out of the box, but you with Varnish 4, the VMODs should have access to the body and should be capable of creating a new response.